# Disk doesn't appear in blkid but does appear in lsblk

Tags: rhel, mount, disk, lsblk, libblkid

When we do the following on a RHEL lab machine:

```
lsblk | grep sdd
sdd                8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
```

we get the sdd disk, but when we do `blkid` as the following:

```
blkid  | grep sdd
```

we do not get any output.

We re-scan the disk as:

```
echo 1>/sys/class/block/sdd/device/rescan
```

but `blkid` still does not recognize the sdd disk.

```
blkid  | grep sdd
```

Why is that, and what we can do about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About [`blkid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html):

> When device is specified [… (irrelevant)]. If none is given, all partitions or unpartitioned devices **which appear** in `/proc/partitions` are shown, **if** they are recognized.

While [`lsblk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html)

> lists information about **all** available or the specified block devices.

<sup>[Emphasis mine]</sup>

Specify a device:

```
blkid /dev/sdd
```

Empty output indicates there in no structure from which `blkid` could read attributes (e.g. after `wipefs -a /dev/sdd`).